# CodeIgniter MySQL count different rows

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i want to count the different rows in CodeIgniter...

I have a table like this

```
NAME | ZIPCODE
Mike | 12345
Marc | 51233
TEST | 12345
```

Now i want a Result of "2" cause there 2 different Zipcodes.

I tried so much, but dont get this :(

```
$this->db->select('zipcode, count(*)');
$getAll = $this->db->get('ads');
echo $getAll->num_rows();
```

but dont get result of or anything... idk how i can make this. 
Please help

//EDIT:
Okay i found it. Sorry for Question. Here is the Answer

```
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->select('zipcode');
$getAll = $this->db->get('ads');
echo $getAll->num_rows();
```

Comment: So, the question is answered?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
$query = $this->db->query('select count(1) as x from your_table_name group by zipcode');

$row= $query->row();
$x = $row->x;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use group_by() in your query as follows.

```
$this->db->select('zipcode', 'count(*) as totalcount');
$this->db->group_by('zipcode'); 
$this->db->get('ads');
```